# What is the language set of Adobe Creative Cloud?

Tags: language, adobe-creative-cloud

Adobe is releasing so many "sub version" of the same software version. like Adobe Audition (LS20) and Illustrator (LS6) and (LS16) ... and so one.

after some searching I figured out this is the Language set of the software.

my question is what is this number referring to? (I know it is referring to the number of languages, but what are those language?), and how to know my installed Language set? where can I find an online reference for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is the language set of Adobe Creative Cloud?

> One big improvement with CC is **Adobe no longer splits out files into different language sets – all languages are now included in a single multilingual download**, including English, Western European (French, German, Dutch, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, …), Eastern European (Russian, Polish, Hungarian, Czech, …), Middle Eastern (Hebrew, Arabic), and Asian (Japanese, Korean, Chinese).
>
> **So if you need to install additional languages, just run the same installer again and choose another language.**

Source [Creative Cloud 2014 Downloads: Adobe CC 2014 Direct Links / Trials](http://prodesigntools.com/adobe-cc-2014-direct-download-links.html)

---

#### I know it is referring to the number of languages, but what are those languages?

> **CC applications**
>
> As a Creative Cloud member, you can download and install CC applications in any language in which the products are available. Unlike buying traditional software, where all components are in the same language, Creative Cloud lets you select from multiple languages for each product. So you can have different language versions of each product depending on your needs.
>
> **See the product links in the system requirements section for a
> complete list of languages for each CC product.**

...

> **System requirements**

...

> Refer to the following tech specs pages for a complete list of system requirements for each product.

There is a series of links for each product.

For example:

> [Adobe Audition CC](https://creative.adobe.com/products/audition)

If you follow this link and look at the `Languages` tab you will see:

> - Deutsch
> - English
> - Español
> - Français
> - Italiano
> - 简体中文
> - 日本語
> - 한국어

Source [System requirements | Creative Cloud](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/system-requirements.html)